# how to fix the Role Hierarchy I am using for method level security

Tags: jsp, spring-security

I am implementing method-level security (@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_OD')")) on the controller functions in a large (28 controllers of various sizes) jsp project.  The permissions are complex, but some of the roles are hierarchical:

ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_OD ROLE_OD > ROLE_PD ROLE_PD > MEMBER ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_BGC

Currently the role hierarchy works if it consists of one level (ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_OD), but doesn't work for multiple levels (ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_OD ROLE_OD > ROLE_PD), and I can't figure out why.

I don't know if it matters, but I have customized the User and UserPrivilege objects, so that I can verify in the controller methods that users are restricted to accessing only their information.  All of that works, and I can access the @AuthenticationPrincipal User user parameter from within each method successfully.  I can also see the grantedAuthorities for each user to verify that they should have access, when access is denied.

I have never entered a question before, so I am not sure how much code is enough, or too much, but I will try to give you everything you need to help me.

I have researched all documentation I could find for 2 days, and tried 5 different ways of setting up the project.  The way I have it now, it works for one level using @PreAuthorize, but will not work for @Secure, even if I enable it for that.  I also noticed that if I don't put the roles in descending order within the hierarchy, then it won't even compile.  I tried the syntax a thousand different ways.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_OD')")
@RequestMapping(value="/testAccess",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void testAccess(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {
    System.out.println("user has access to this method!");
}

    @Configuration
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
    public class MethodLevelConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy(){
    RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
    roleHierarchy.setHierarchy("ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_OD and ROLE_OD > ROLE_PD");
    return roleHierarchy;
    }

    @Bean
    public RoleVoter roleVoter() {
        return new RoleHierarchyVoter(roleHierarchy());
    }

    @Autowired
    private RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy;


    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {

    DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(new PermissionEvaluatorImpl());
                expressionHandler.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy);
    return expressionHandler;
    }

    }
    @Configuration
    // @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


        @Autowired
        private PasswordEncoder myPasswordEncoder;

        @Autowired
        private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

        @Autowired
        private WebAuthenticationDetailsSourceImpl authenticationDetailsSource;

        @Bean
        public WebAuthenticationDetailsSourceImpl authenticationDetailsSource() {
            return new WebAuthenticationDetailsSourceImpl();
        }

        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder myPasswordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }


        @Bean
        public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
            AuthenticationProviderImpl authProvider = new AuthenticationProviderImpl();
            authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
            authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(myPasswordEncoder());
            return authProvider;
        }

        @Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
        @Override
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(myPasswordEncoder);
        }


        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    [.antMatchers() here...]

            http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
        }
```

If I log in as a user with ROLE_PD or ROLE_ADMIN, I get the printed message "user has access to this method!"

If I log in as a user with ROLE_OD, I get error: .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to separate your role hierarchies with the line separator, see [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#authz-hierarchical-roles):

> **11.1.4 Hierarchical Roles**
>
> [...]
>
> The use of a role-hierarchy allows you to configure which roles (or authorities) should include others. An extended version of Spring Security’s RoleVoter, `RoleHierarchyVoter`, is configured with a `RoleHierarchy`, from which it obtains all the "reachable authorities" which the user is assigned. A typical configuration might look like this:
>
> ```java
> <bean id="roleVoter" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleHierarchyVoter">
>     <constructor-arg ref="roleHierarchy" />
> </bean>
> <bean id="roleHierarchy"
>     class="org.springframework.security.access.hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl">
>     <property name="hierarchy">
>         <value>
>             ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_STAFF
>             ROLE_STAFF > ROLE_USER
>             ROLE_USER > ROLE_GUEST
>         </value>
>     </property>
> </bean>
> ```

and source code of [`RoleHierarchyImpl`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/50adb6abcb71e8c91bff13871c7ef07eb6d51225/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/access/hierarchicalroles/RoleHierarchyImpl.java#L164):

> [...]
>
> ```java
> /**
>  * Parse input and build the map for the roles reachable in one step: the higher role
>  * will become a key that references a set of the reachable lower roles.
>  */
> private void buildRolesReachableInOneStepMap() {
>     this.rolesReachableInOneStepMap = new HashMap<>();
>     for (String line : this.roleHierarchyStringRepresentation.split("\n")) {
> ```
>
> [...]

Comment: thanks so much -- I did see that formatted role list, but did not put 2 and 2 together, to come up with the fact that I had to enter line breaks between them!